# Help identify this inductor / choke / coil

Tags: identification, inductor, toroidal

This is from a Socket 370 motherboard (Epox EP-MVP3G-M) that has some burst caps.  Sadly it also seems to have taken one of the inductors(?) with it.

[image: ok inductor and failed inductor]

I'm having a heck of a time trying to order something equivalent.

It measures about 15mm in diameter by 7mm thick (outside dimensions).  The mounting holes on the motherboard are 9mm apart.  The wire is 1mm and it looks like 7 turns?

I have no idea how to figure this out from what I have.  The only tools I have is a cheap multimeter and a soldering iron.

[image: motherboard location of parts]

Yes, it looks rough...

Comment: That looks bad. You may just re-use that inductor. But, the motherboard will not work. I am 99.999% betting on that.

Comment: just replace the wire with the same diameter and turns. I'd also suspect other problems.

Comment: The wire on that inductor is corroded so I have my doubts about using it. Maybe getting some wire and rewinding it would be a good option.  The coating on the core is coming off as well, though that probably doesn’t matter as much.
So far it’s just stuff on the surface as far as I can see. Need to order the replacement caps and would like to order that part as well. Just don’t know what it is.